# add head content in codeigniter sub folder

Tags: codeigniter

i use sub folder in controller like admin_panel

in admin_panel / main.php i use this code

```
public function index()
    {
        $h_data['title'] = 'admin';
        $c_data = array();
        $this->parser->parse('admin/head',$h_data);
        $this->parser->parse('admin/index',$c_data);
    }
```

and head.php in view/admin contain :

```
<html>

<head>



<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/font.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" />

 <!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/admin_style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<title> {title} </title>

</head>
```

asstes folder exist in root project but when refresh page all head tags return 404 and not found ???

Comment: Try to give full path to your folder

Comment: i usee  $h_data['base_url'] = base_url(); and add {base_url} to view but not work yet .

Comment: are you using `.htaccess` to remove `index.php` from url?

Comment: yes of course . RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: @jogesh_pi does this problem relavent with .htaccess file?

Comment: @user3243573 because you have to permit the assets folder through htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find answer this error occure for .htaccess not suitable code . i use this htaccess and work fine :)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
public function index() {
// Load Parser library or autoload it.
$this->load->library('parser');

$data['title'] = "Page Title";
$data['base_url'] = base_url(); // Make sure you add url helper to autoload.

// May need to add true, i.e $this->parser->parse('header', $data, true);
$data['header'] = $this->parser->parse('header', $data); 

// May need to add true, i.e $this->parser->parse('footer', NULL, true); Null No Data
$data['footer'] = $this->parser->parse('footer');

$this->parser->parse('content', $data);

}
```

**On Content View Area's**

```
<?php echo $header;?>

Content

<?php echo $footer;?>
```

**Header View Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<base href="<?php echo base_url();?>"></base>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/admin/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/admin/css/custom.css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/admin/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/admin/js/filemanager.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

**Footer View Example**

```
<footer id="footer">
<br />
</footer>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Auto load url helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array(
    'url',
    'file',
    'form',
    'text',
    'html',
    'date'
 );
```

Comment: i usee $h_data['base_url'] = base_url(); and add {base_url} to view but not work yet .

Comment: Updated my answer: Just use $data rather than $h_data try keep all the same also make sure you have auto loaded url library.

Comment: You may need to load the `$this->load->library('parser')` you can autoload that is well in autoload.php

Comment: i use all this code but notwork yet :( i check all link src in inspect element and all link are right but not working . GET http://site.dev/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 Error !!!!!!

Comment: Did you see how I done my header. With base url. yours cannot work like ../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: in head.php : <script type="text/javascript" src="{base_url}assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> and other same this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74469/discussion-between-mustang83-and-user3243573).